# Which system calls are called when file is updated from gedit?

Tags: gedit, system

If any file is updated using gedit then internally which system calls are called or which algos are called ??

What is the way of getting that list of operations occurred when file is updated from gedit.

Comment: But starce or Istrace are used via terminal. I want tracing of all system calls when file is updated from gedit that is from GUI.

Comment: @user3797948 that makes no difference. A program is a program, just open a terminal and run `strace gedit file.txt 2>strace.out`. The file `strace.out` will contain the strace output.

Comment: @user3797948 Here by using this command I am able to get events of file opening using gedit ,but how do i get stracing of the file updation using gedit.